# How do I fix my discord bot breaking when waiting for multiple `wait_for(reaction_add)` is called?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have a verification process on my server that takes the inputs of the new member (First name and section and whatever) then sends it to a channel in a server where admins click on an emote to accept/deny the person. The problem is, once 2+ people open tickets, it basically becomes unusable.

To make me sane while writing it, I'll make a scenario.

1. `x`, `y` join the server.
2. Both send verification requests.
3. Admin accepts request for `x`.
4. Instead of `x` being approved, `x` **and** `y` gets approved.

This is really bugging me as I might as well do it without the `wait_for()` checks.

Code:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member: discord.Member):
        channel = member.guild.get_channel(734637251681583164)
        verichannel = member.guild.get_channel(849593765097373696)

        embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f"Welcome {member.name}, keep in mind that this is NOT an [woah privacy] server!",
        description=f"This is not a family-friendly server, so please leave if you're not comfortable with it. \n Make sure to read <#734639183737389060> & <#750190162000216215> before proceeding! \n To get access to our server, please verify at <#848430448223977512>.",
        color=0x2ecc71
        )
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
        await channel.send(member.mention, embed=embed)

        # DM verification
        def check(m):
            return m.guild == None and m.author == member

        awaitingverification = discord.Embed(title="Verification Request", description=f"User: {member.mention}", color = 0x01c618)
        embed= discord.Embed(title="What is this?",
                              description="This is a verification program for the unofficial [woah privacy] server. We do this to ensure the safety and privacy of our members. We are going to ask information that will be sent to our admins for further processing.",
                              color=0x00d118)
        embed.set_author(name="[woah privacy] Verification program")
        embed.add_field(name="1st Question: What is your first name?", value="Example: Jordan",
                        inline=False)
        await member.send(embed=embed)
        try:
            first_name = await self.bot.wait_for('message',timeout=30, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await member.send("Timed out. Re-Join.")
            return
        awaitingverification.add_field(name="First Name", value=first_name.content, inline=True)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Verification: 2nd step",
                              description="This is the second step of the verification process.", color=0x00d118)
        embed.set_author(name="[woah privacy] Verification program")
        embed.add_field(name="2nd Question: What is your section? If you are not enrolled, reply 'Visitor'.", value="Example: LS208", inline=False)
        await member.send(embed=embed)
        try:
            section = await self.bot.wait_for('message',timeout=30, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await member.send("Timed out. Re-Join.")
            return
        awaitingverification.add_field(name="Section", value=section.content, inline=True)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Verification: 3rd step",
                              description="This is the third step of the verification process.", color=0x00d118)
        embed.set_author(name="[woah privacy] Verification program")
        embed.add_field(name="3rd Question: Do you agree with all our rules? Reply with 'Yes' if you do.",
                        value="Below is a skimmed version of our full rules, so be sure to read them after.",
                        inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="This is not an official [woah privacy] server.", value="If there is one, then... we dont care.",
                        inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Names in the server are your real first names.", value="If not: kicked out the door.",
                        inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="This is not a family friendly server.",
                        value="It's a mess here sometimes but thats what's good about it.", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Don't be an asshole.", value="We wont hesitate to swing that ban hammer.", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="No loopholes.", value="Because.. Well... It's bad.", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Read the Discord ToS (Terms of Service)", value="TL:DR: Must be 13+ to use discord.",
                        inline=False)
        await member.send(embed=embed)
        try:
            rulestatus = await self.bot.wait_for('message',timeout=30, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await member.send("Timed out. Re-Join.")
            return
        awaitingverification.add_field(name="Rules", value=rulestatus.content, inline=True)
        awaitingverification.set_footer(text=": Student, : Visitor, : Deny and Kick")
        await member.send("Thank you. Your application will be processed in due time.")
        verification = await verichannel.send(embed=awaitingverification)
        await verification.add_reaction("")
        await verification.add_reaction("")
        await verification.add_reaction("")

        def check(reaction, user):
            return str(reaction.emoji) in ["", "", ""] and user != self.bot.user


        reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "":
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Verification Request", description=f"User: {member.mention}")
            embed.add_field(name="Status:", value=f"Approved by {user}: Student", inline=False)
            await verification.edit(embed=embed)
            await verification.clear_reactions()
            role1 = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Students")
            await member.add_roles(role1)
            if discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name=f"Section: {section.content}"):
                sectionrole = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name=f"Section: {section.content}")
                await member.add_roles(sectionrole)
            else:
                await member.guild.create_role(name=f"Section: {section.content}")
                sectionrole = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name=f"Section: {section.content}")
                await member.add_roles(sectionrole)
            await member.send("Your Verification Request has been granted as Student. Have a good time and check the rules!")
            return

        elif str(reaction.emoji) == "":
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Verification Request", description=f"User: {member.mention}")
            embed.add_field(name="Status:", value=f"Approved by {user}: Visitor", inline=False)
            await verification.edit(embed=embed)
            await verification.clear_reactions()
            role2 = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Visitors")
            await member.add_roles(role2)
            await member.send("Your Verification Request has been granted as Visitor. Have a good time and check the rules!")
            return

        elif str(reaction.emoji) == "":
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Verification Request", description=f"User: {member.mention}")
            embed.add_field(name="Status:", value=f"Denied by {user}", inline=False)
            await verification.edit(embed=embed)
            await verification.clear_reactions()
            await member.send("Your Verification Request has been denied.")
            await member.kick()
            return
```

p.s sorry, I didn't skim any of the code, I wanted to share it as is because maybe it's my spaghetti's fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, check if it's the same message in `check`:

```py
        verification = await verichannel.send(embed=awaitingverification)
        await verification.add_reaction("")
        await verification.add_reaction("")
        await verification.add_reaction("")

        def check(reaction, user):
            return str(reaction.emoji) in ["", "", ""] and user != self.bot.user and reaction.message == verification


        reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
```

---

**References:**

- [reaction.message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Reaction.message)